# Check if a range of numbers are within another range in PHP, or MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

It would have been ideal to do what I want to do in a MySQL query but I think I maybe quite limited after looking at BETWEEN.

So I've been looking at PHP...

So I have 2 numbers for a property size for example 200 - 3000

I then need to check if those 2 numbers and the range between them fall within another range, so in this example $sizemin = 500 and $sizemax = 1000

I've looked at the range() function but I can only seem to get it partially working.

Comment: What about 500 - 4000 ?

Comment: so you want a sql solution, a php solution or a mixture? bit unclear to me

Comment: are you just trying to check that the difference between two numbers is between sizeMin and sizeMax?

Comment: @MarkFisher The OP wants a MySQL solution. They're simply uncertain as to whether such a solution is available.

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks, though i'm not sure why there's a php element to this then. Seems like a curve ball, and OP hasn't clarified anywhere. Reads like "tried mysql - too hard, now moved to php to solve, here's some php variables and a function i may or may not have vaguely tried". also the title suggests either of the two, yet there isn't a question in the whole post.

Comment: @MarkFisher The OP assumed (incorrectly) that a pure MySQL solution was unavailable, hence the curve ball.

Comment: @MarkFisher sorry shall be more clear in the future! I was pretty sure there was a solution to this with MySQL but I'm no pro and wasn't sure if I could do it with PHP (if there was no MySQL solution) before my query. Ta

Answer (score 1):

Uhm... with BETWEEN in MySQL:

```
SELECT num1, num2 FROM table WHERE (num1 BETWEEN num3 AND num4) AND (num2 BETWEEN num3 AND num4);
```

If you get a result from the query, the numbers are inside the range...